# Opportunity Name Workflow Rule - Creates name twice

Tags: workflow, process-builder, opportunity

I have created Opportunity Name workflow rule as follows

Account.Name & " | " & PRIORVALUE(Name) & " | " & TEXT(Today())

Output is

Account Name | Priorvalue = whatever is entered user | today date in year.month.date

Here is the screenshot of the opportunity

[image: Current opportinity name]

But when my process builder creates renewal opportunities for the future date. the current opportunity name becomes prior value and created opportunity looks like this

[image: Future opportunity name]

Is there a way of resolving this? or writing a better workflow rule which can take care of this? Functionally i am open for suggestions as well.

Best Regards
Prashant

Comment: sorry it is  not validation rule but a workflow rule which i have written, sorry for the mistake i made in the question

Comment: You can **[edit]** your own question to make any changes you like. Please don't use comments to append additional information to a question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
Account.Name & " | " &
IF(CONTAINS(Name, " | "),
MID(Name, FIND(Name, " | "), FIND(Name, " | ", FIND(Name, " | ") + 1) - FIND(Name, " | ")),
Name) &
" | " & TEXT(Today())
```

The lack of variables make this particularly verbose; if possible, I would consider using a trigger instead. This would also reduce the CPU time used in this particular situation.

Comment: I tried your validation rule, when my renewal opportunity is created, prior value is missing in the new opportunity i.e., an original entry which i have manually entered is not replicating in the new opportunity name